# Postman Mock Server matching algorithm logic for request body param

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have two scenarios for the following API URL.

> POST http://{{ip_port}}/oauth/token

1. When I put the user name and password correctly, it should return
   200 and mock json response.
2. When I put user name and password incorrectly, it should return 401 and mocked json(error).

In `Postman` Mock server, I noticed that there is no matching algorithm logic for request param.

I want to filter by request param and return related mock responses. I don't want to add two `URLs(/token and /failedtoken)` for above scenarios.

Currently Postman only support three logic for matching algorithm logic.

1. Properly formatted responses
2. HTTP method
3. Filter by URL

Is there any way to add only one URL for many scenarios in Postman Mock Server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Postman Mock Server [now supports matching by request body](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3602#issuecomment-486170612). You can use it by specifying a custom header (`x-mock-match-request-body` to `true`).

You can also check out an example that demonstrates how this feature works by going to `New->Templates` and searching for `Request Body Matching`.