# Retrieve different post request responses based on different body inputs

Tags: post, postman, mockserver

I am setting up a mock server for a third party API using postman. My goal is to get specific POST request responses based on different body inputs. I was wondering if this was something possible to do using postman, and if so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman Mock Server matching algorithm logic for request body param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035389/postman-mock-server-matching-algorithm-logic-for-request-body-param)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get different responses based on the body of the request, it's the same as with the GET Requests, but you should also send the `x-mock-match-request-body` header with a value set to `true` in the request header while hitting the mock URL.

See: [Mocking GraphQL queries](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock_servers/mocking_with_examples/#mocking-graphql-queries)